# eval function gives SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, eval

I am trying to make a calculator using react,and I am not able to use 'eval' in the input field. this following code gives this error-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class myApp extends React.Component {
  state = {
    equation: "",
  };

  handleClick = (e) => {
    this.setState({ equation: e.target.value });
    console.log(eval(this.state.equation));
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={this.state.equation}
          onChange={this.handleClick}
        ></input>
        <h1>{this.state.equation}</h1>
        <button onClick>enter</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default myApp;
```

Error-

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input
```

Why does this error occur and how can I fix this ?

Comment: did you try `window.eval` ?

Comment: No i did not try

Comment: try this one: `window.eval(this.state.equation)`

Answer (score 1):

You need to first set the value after putting in `eval()` method.
`eval('10 + 10')` working fine but when value is `eval('10+')` is throw the `error` in javaScript as well.

In react after set value you can convert or try vie `eval()`.

If you enter value its should be output like below :

```
1
10
10+
10+2
10+20
```

So when value is `10+` its throw the error.

You can read more about [eval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval#dont-use-it)

You can try this way.

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const App = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState({ equation: "" });

  useEffect(() => {}, [state.equation]);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    console.log(value);
    setState({ equation: value });
  };

  const handleOnClick = (e) => {
    console.log(eval(state.equation));
    setState({ equation: eval(state.equation) });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={state.equation} onChange={handleChange} />
      <h1>{state.equation}</h1>
      <button onClick={handleOnClick}>enter</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`setState` inside event handlers is asynchronous - this mean it will update `this.state` after event handler finishes (this allows `react` to batch multiple `setState`s calls into one update).

In your case you are calling eval with previous state value - `""` (and this gives an error).

Instead of using `this.state.equation` try:

```
console.log(eval(e.target.value));
```

Comment: No this is not working and it is giving me the same error

Comment: What is the input of the `eval` then?

Comment: Input if eval is the input user enters

Comment: Please give me example input

Comment: 3+3 is an example input